# git: will I be able to get all history even if I delete my cloned workspace?

Tags: git, workspace

Hi This is a basic question on git and its central repository.

I created a bare init in repo, and then cloned the bare repo and added all my files to git, and pushed to origin.

Now if I delete the workspace where I have cloned, will the data be secure in repo (remote origin)

I've used SVN, and git too , but have not tried deleting workspaces.
This cleaning might be often required since anytime I want to work on, I will pull from repo, and work on, and after the feature is completed and pushed, I will delete my workspace.

Is this proper method?

ask me back if I have to specify some more data?

Comment: Why you need to delete the local repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you pushed to remote repository will be available even if you delete the local repository.

There is a difference between cloning and pulling. Once you delete a local repository you have to clone it.

There is no need to delete a local repository, if you want to update the local repository then you can pull the changes.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that repo will hold data.
reason for deleting: repo area is assigned to us, and where I keep my workspace has some restriction (all users use this area for testing) and when they are done, they are suppose to clean up). Its better to use local workspace only when request comes for certain feature.